# How to visualize Associated models in Sencha App inspector

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a question about the "sencha app inspector" extension. (chrome)

Is it possible to see the associated models inside a store?
I can see the main model but not the associated models.

If it is possible, how can I find them?

Comment: I would expect that to be on model base, as the associated models are not part of the store, but part of the single model.

Comment: Thanks Proto Bassi as always.. :-)  I see the model associated is created in a ext-data-store-XX  Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Right now this is not possible, but it's a feature we're [actively looking to add](https://github.com/senchalabs/AppInspector/issues/77).

Note: you should probably ask these kinds of questions on the Sencha forums. That way I'm more likely to see it :-)